# Filtered LOD calculations in DAX expression Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-field

I have created LOD expressions in Tableau before which dynamically calculate when filters are applied. I am trying to achieve similar functionality in Power BI. I am very new to Power BI so I probably didn't ask google the right question. I simply want a column that shows the average sales over my "Filtered" data set. The closest I cam was using the Calculate(average(table[column]),All(table)) but that does not dynamically change when I apply the date slider. If I filter for 1/1 - 1/5 I want that average. Change the date range, the average should change.

[image: AVG STDEV]

Thank you.

Comment: There is a great, free, introductory training course for DAX at https://www.sqlbi.com/p/introducing-dax-video-course/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CALCULATE( 
   AVERAGE(Table[Column]),
   ALLSELECTED()
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work. It still gave me the average for the entire data set. filters had no effect.

Comment: This formula must be a Measure, not a calculated column. Calculated columns are "fixed", they don't react to slicers and other filters. To solve the problem, instead of calculating this formula in a column, create a new measure ([Average Sales]), and drop it into the table.

Comment: Bingo! Thats what I was looking for...However I have another similar issue. Basically the overall objective it to find outliers for different date ranges. I need to find the Standard Deviation of an aggregated dataset vs the underlying detail. I have multiple people selling per day and instead of finding the SDEV.P at the individual day level. I need to average sales by person and do the SDEV.P off of those averaged sales. Added screenshots to original post.

Comment: That's a much more complex problem than the original one. I think if you post it as a new, well-described question, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `ALLEXCEPT()` function. In this case you would do something like

```
CALCULATE(AVERAGE(table[column]), ALLEXCEPT(table, table[date]))
```

that is basically saying that you want to remove all filters on the table except the filters on the date column.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work. It gave me the average partitioned by date and since there is one record per date...it just replicated the sales column

Comment: As with the other answer, this needs to be a measure not a calculated column.

Comment: is there any way you know how to implement the above in tableau?